# Why syslog stop writing log after edit certain log?

Tags: linux, logging, message, syslog

I using centos5.8
I wonder why syslog stop writing log after certain log edited.

for example, after cut the line of /var/log/messages, syslog doesn't write new log.
Just old logs are remained.

But If I delete the messages file and reboot the system, syslog works fine.

Is there any ways, syslogd write new logs continuosely after edit certain log??

Answer (score 1):

It depends how exactly a file is edited.

Remember that `syslogd` keeps the file open for continuously writing. If your editor writes a new file with the old name after `unlink()`ing or `rename()`ing the old file, that old file remains in operation for syslogd. The new file, however, remains untouched.

It can be informed about the new file to be used with the `HUP` signal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that would depend on how syslogd works. I should mention that it's probably *not* a good idea to edit system log files, by the way :-)

You may have been caught out by one peculiarity of the way UNIX file systems can work.

If process A has a file open and is writing to it, process B can go and just delete the file (either with something like `rm` or, as seems likely here, in an edit session which deletes the old file and rewrites a new one).

Deletion of that original file does *not* destroy the data, it simply breaks the link between the file name (the directory entry) and that data.

A process that has the original file open can continue to write to it as long as it wants and, since there's no entry in the file system for it, you can't (easily) see it.

A *new* file with that file name may be bought into existence but process A will not be writing to it, it will be writing to the original. There will be no connection between the old and the new file.

You'll sometimes see this effect when you're running low on disk space and decide to delete a lot of files to clear it up somewhat. If processes have those files open, deleting them will not help you at all since the space is still being used (and quite possibly the usage is increasing).

You have to both delete the files *and* somehow convince those processes holding them open to relinquish them.

Comment: Nice explanation. So how do we tell system to use newly created messages file? I removed the existing messages file in order to free up the space. The space did not clean up and now newly created messages file is not being used to write logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you edited /var/log/syslog you need to restart the syslog service afterwards, because syslogd needs to open the file handle again.